# Problems installing windows server 2003 on a Dell PowerEdge 1800

Tags: windows-server-2003, dell, dell-poweredge

I have a dell poweredge 1800 that I have set up to raid 5 and the array is fine, I then install the build and update utility from media it then prompts me for the open manage server administrator v6.5 when I insert this media it doesn't install but just stays at 15% and prompts for the media again even though it is the correct media. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not aware that you can install the OS with the Server Administrator CD. You can install the OS with the Server Assistant CD (are they both on the same CD?). The Server Assistant CD should prompt you for the OS install media.

Comment: I actually downloaded the drivers from the dell website. [From here](http://ftp.dell.com/Pages/Drivers/poweredge-1800.html). Maybe I have the wrong drivers, it has been a real pain

Comment: Gotcha. I haven't used the SBU. Try this: http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails/Product/poweredge-1850?driverId=R146318&osCode=WNET&fileId=2731115812&languageCode=EN&categoryId=SM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get around this is to de-select Dell OMSA/OpenManage during deployment with the SBU. This should get you around that problem, and OMSA can be installed after OS deployment is complete. I don't believe OMSA is actually included in the SBU (or at least not correctly), though it is selected as an installation option by default. You'd likely need to have OMSA on a separate install media to insert during the process otherwise.

Comment: yup, it's an old thing, used to be a very common reason to call dell support - that checkbox is very easy to overlook